# Desktop Sharing to work from another computer

Tags: linux, open-source, networking, remote-desktop, sharing

Context: I have my personal laptop and my work laptop (both Linux) but I'm tired of the hassle of plugging cables whenever I'm going to use one or the other. So, I want LAN access to my work laptop i.e. share it with my personal one. Btw, I'm a programmer so I'll only be coding, compiling, listening to music, having meetings, and manipulating windows, and I just want a smooth experience. I won't be using very heavy software like Blender, for example.

Because I intend to use this for commercial purposes, I can't use Teamviewer, NoMachine, Parsec, or similar.

I took a look at the current alternatives, tested a few ones, and would like your second opinion/suggestion as well (because I don't want to overthink/overtest stuff even more):

- Gnome's Desktop Sharing looks to work just fine. A coworker of mine uses it but in my case, I use KDE, so I would have to figure out a way of installing it for other DEs or using something else.
- KRDC is super laggy so no, thank you.
- Chrome Remote Desktop works pretty well from what I tested.
- I read about XRDP, TigerVNC, and Apache Guacamole. They might work but I haven't tested them yet.
- Moonlight looks cool and all but because I have an AMD GPU and an Intel Graphics I'd have to use Sunshine (apparently) so I'll try to fix it later.
- OpenNX, X2Go, and FreeRDP look like alternatives as well but I haven't really read what they're about, yet.

Answer (score 0):

So the biggest factor here is whether you are running KDE via KWin *(X11)* or KWayland *(Wayland)*.

***For X11 (KWin):***
You have a couple different options here:

- **TigerVNC** - If you want all windows on the remote machine to appear as one window on the local machine, using TigerVNC is a no-brainer.
- **SSH Tunnel** - If you are going to set it up so that each window on the remote machine appears as a separate window on the local machine, you can just [Forward X11 over SSH as explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely).

  - ***NOTE:***  This will work for graphics, but if you want to forward the sound you will need to use [PipeWire's pulse-tunnel module](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_pulse_tunnel.html) *and* [PipeWire's zeroconf-discover module](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_zeroconf_discover.html).

---

***For Wayland (KWayland):***

**VNC** - VNC does not currently work *natively* with *KWayland*.  You could run it on top of *XWayland*, but in order to run it natively you would have to switch compositors.  As you pointed out if you were using Gnome you could use *gnome-remote-desktop* or if you were using a *wlroots* based compositor like [Sway](http://swaywm.org/), [Hyprland](https://github.com/vaxerski/Hyprland), [qtile](https://github.com/qtile/qtile), or [several others listed here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wlroots/wlroots/-/wikis/Projects-which-use-wlroots) you could use [wayvnc](https://github.com/any1/wayvnc).

- **SSH Tunnel** - You could go this route like with X11 using [Waypipe as described here](https://github.com/neonkingfr/waypipe) for GUI's and then using the same method I mentioned earlier to tunnel PipeWire via a virtual PulseAudio Sink.

---

If you are using *KWayland*, I would highly recommend just going into KDE's Settings and switching the Window Manager over to *KWin* and save yourself allot of headache.  I personally have only used Wayland under the two *wlroots* based compositors *Hyprland* or *Sway*.  I don't know that you get that much benefit from running KDE under Wayland; but then again, I don't ever use KDE or Gnome.

Comment: I use KDE on X11. I'm taking a look at how to set up a private VNC or something very similar. Still researching

Comment: You may want to check out a really good write up on it over on the Unix exchange [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593570/how-to-setup-a-vnc-server-on-linux).  The post discusses various ways to secure it and uses an example setup of KDE on X11.